# Typing React props returns errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using ANT design and react for my application. I have 2 components:

```js
//PARENT
const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  function onChange(
    pagination: TablePaginationConfig,
    filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>,
    sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[],
    extra
  ) {
    console.log("params", sorter);
    setState([sorter.order, sorter.field]);
  }
  console.log("params", state);

  return <CustomTable onChange={onChange} />;
};
```

and:

```js
//CHILD
const CustomTable = ({
  onChange?: (pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>, sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[], extra: TableCurrentDataSource<RecordType>) => void;
}) => {
  return (
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />
  )
}
```

How you can see i try to add types for `onChange` function. One time as a prop in CHILD component and one time in side PARENT component, but i got an error trying to add the next types for `sorter` parameter:
`sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[],`. The issue is when i try to change the `RecordType` generic, because i don't know what value should i add there. Now i got:
`Property 'order' does not exist on type 'SorterResult<any> | SorterResult<any>[]` and `Property 'field' does not exist on type 'SorterResult<any> | SorterResult<any>[]'.`.How to add types for this function parameter (`sorter`) in my case?
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-antd4150-forked-ie0o5?file=/index.tsx:341-761

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass type while destructuring an Object. Please modify the `CustomTable` as:

```
interface RecordType {
 key: string,
 name: string,
 chinese: number,
 math: number,
 english: number,
}

type Props = {
 onChange?: (pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>, sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[], extra: TableCurrentDataSource<RecordType>) => void,
}

const CustomTable = ({
  onChange,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />
  )
}
```

Comment: from where to import `RecordType`?

Comment: could you help?

Comment: it can be the type of your data as well as `unknown` based on your usecase.  Added a sample code above.

Comment: what to type as unknown?

Comment: If you don't know the data or if it'll change dynamically, you can type it as `unknown`.But in the example the data is static and hence I've added the RecordType interface matching the structure of data given.